# Type Narrowing with Array.some()

Tags: typescript

Consider an array `arr` of type `(A|B)[]`. Consider the following code

```
function isA(x: any): x is A;
function isB(x: any): x is B;

if(arr.some(isA)) return
arr // should be of type B[]
```

This doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: You don't, unfortunately. See [ms/TS#47574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47574), marked as a design limitation of the language. TS lacks *negated types* so there's no way to say `arr is not B[]` in a way that makes the type guard do something when returning `false`.  You should use `every` instead.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

it is not correct from the logical point of view ((A|B) could consist and As and Bs) and it is not possible to make a method such as `.some` a typeguard for class instance itself.

It is possible to narrow the type for the whole predicate however, if it helps you

```
function isAArr(arr: A[] | B[]): arr is A[] {
   return arr.length === 0 || arr[0] instanceof A;
}

const arr: A[] | B[] = [];

if(isAArr(arr)) {
 // here arr type is narrowed to A[]
}
```